# Scrapy empty .json file return

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am trying to get data from a website.

Everything seems to be correct (xpath was tested on the shell):

```
>>> scrapy shell "https://stopcovid19.fr/"

>>> for cat in response.xpath("//ul[@class='level0 submenu']/li/a"):
    {
        'name': cat.xpath("./span/text()").get(),
        'link': cat.xpath("./@href").get(),
    }
```

Here is the code:

```
import scrapy

class ToScrapeSpiderXPath(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'categories'
    start_urls = ['https://stopcovid19.fr']

    def parse(self, response):

        for cat in response.xpath("//ul[@class='level0 submenu']/li/a"):
            yield {
                'name': cat.xpath("./span/text()").get(),
                'link': cat.xpath("./@href").get(),
            }
```

But when I try to get result on a json file with the following code, the file is empty.

```
scrapy crawl categories -O categories.json
```

Could you help me? Sorry in advance, this is my first program...

Comment: I know this isn't so helpful, but your code works fine for me. The only differences is I ran with `scrapy runspider <filename.py> -O categories.json`

Comment: This helps a lot!! my file was in the wrong folder. Now it is working :) THANKS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to add contains() function to your xpath:

```
//ul[contains(@class, 'level0 submenu')]
```

try like that:

```
for cat in response.xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'level0 submenu')]/li/a"):
    ...
```

so spider looks like:

```
import scrapy


class ToScrapeSpiderXPath(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'categories'
    start_urls = ['https://stopcovid19.fr']

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        for cat in response.xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'level0 submenu')]/li/a"):
            yield {
                'name': cat.xpath("./span/text()").get(),
                'link': cat.xpath("./@href").get(),
            }
```

and run the script like:

```
scrapy crawl categories -o file.json
```

++++
EDIT
++++
the code is running well but the spider was not saved in the right file... Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer. Both are working on the shell but both return empty json file.

Comment: @Adrien82 just run the script, all works for me perfectly with data in file.json

[
{"name": "Masques chirurgicaux", "link": "https://stopcovid19.fr/masques/masque-chirurgical.html"},

Comment: @Adrien82 what scrapy version do you have?

Comment: Hi, Found my error: I was saving my spider in a wrong file. When launching it it was an old version running.... Thanks! It really helped me to know the issue was not in the code.

Comment: @Adrien82 may you mark the answer like solution, please?